# Discord.js Spawning Shard Error: Shards still spawning

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, sharding

I'm using discord.js' sharding manager, but whenever I run `node index.js` in the terminal I get this error: `(node:10396) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [SHARDING_IN_PROCESS]: Shards are still being spawned.`

This is my index.js file:

```js
const { ShardingManager } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config');

const manager = new ShardingManager('./bot.js', {
    token: token,
    totalShards: "auto",
    respawn: true
});

manager.spawn();
manager.on("shardCreate", shard => console.log(`[ ShardManager ] Launching shard #${shard.id}`));
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: have you found out what's the issue? I am also facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

According to https://discordjs.guide/sharding/#sharding-file,
maybe consider using launch and also it places `manager.spawn();` to the bottom of `manager.on()` This might solve your problem, hope this helps.

'The above code utilizes the discord.js sharding manager to spawn the recommended amount of shards for your bot. The recommended amount should be approximately 1,000 guilds per shard. Note that you have to attach the event listener to shardCreate before calling .spawn() to prevent a race condition possibly preventing shard 0 from logging the successful launch. Even though you provide the token here, you will still need to send it over to the main bot file in client.login(), so don't forget to do that.'(this was extracted from the guide)